# Trimming a TreeMap to n entries

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a sorted TreeMap, and I want to remove all but the first 10 elements. What is a way to do this? I have considered removing elements from the end of the map while the map size is greater than 10, but I don't know how to do that. Could I convert to a List and then back?

Thanks

Comment: @Laurence Gonsalves: I have sorted my map by values using a value comparator. When I print the map.toString(), I get the values sorted by value order. I just want to print the first ten.

Comment: Gah.... It is a TreeMap. A sorted-by-value TreeMap. I converted it from HashMap to TreeMap in my comparator utility. Sorry! :/ Thanks for spotting my slip up

Answer (score 4):

`HashMap`s don't have a beginning or an end -- they're unordered. The order in which you iterate over the items will be totally unrelated to the order in which you inserted the items. If you can use a LinkedHashMap instead, that class does, in fact, preserve the order in which the items are inserted. Then you could simply iterate over `entrySet()`, calling `remove()` on the iterator for each item after you've iterated over the first ten.

Comment: +1: Another option is to use a TreeMap() with a Comparator if the sorting needs to be something other than the natural ordering of the key. But if by "first 10 elements" the OP meant first ten inserted <K,V> pair then the LinkedHashMap is the way to go here.

Comment: Yes, @CoolBeans, that is what I did.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thought.  Maybe make a map class that is limited in size to 10 elements, and copy/construct your limited map segment that way:

```
package main;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

public class HashMap10<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4943383947326287590L;

    static Map<Integer, String> x = Maps.newHashMap();

    public HashMap10() {
        super();
    }

    public HashMap10(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder) {
        super(initialCapacity, loadFactor, accessOrder);
    }

    public HashMap10(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    public HashMap10(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }

    public HashMap10(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        putAll(m);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if (this.size() == 10) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (java.util.Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> x : m.entrySet()) {
            put(x.getKey(), x.getValue());
        }
    }

}
```

Test it by adding 100 elements to the limited-size map, once by multiple put() calls, and once by using the constructor:

```
package main;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class TestIt {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap10<Integer, String> map10 = new HashMap10<Integer, String>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
            map10.put(i, Integer.toString(i + 100));
        }

        for (Entry<Integer, String> x : map10.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(x.getKey() + "->" + x.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        HashMap<Integer, String> mapUnlimited = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 99; i++) {
            mapUnlimited.put(i, Integer.toString(i + 200));
        }

        HashMap10<Integer, String> anotherMap10 = new HashMap10<Integer, String>(
                mapUnlimited);
        for (Entry<Integer, String> x : anotherMap10.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(x.getKey() + "->" + x.getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

Dump the maps, and you only have maps of 10 elements, whether you added the elements one at a time, or built the map with a constructor:

1->101
2->102
3->103
4->104
5->105
6->106
7->107
8->108
9->109
10->110


1->201
2->202
3->203
4->204
5->205
6->206
7->207
8->208
9->209
10->210

I haven't invested any time in defensive programming, checking for nulls, that sort of thing.  The idea here is that I don't know or care what your original map is.  Linked Map.  Tree Map.  Regular Map.  Whatever order it returns the elements defines what you mean by the "first 10 elements", and my map class will only store those first 10, and ignore any after that.  Now you have your first 10, whatever that means for your map.

Comment: Thanks - this is cool. Had to modify it a bit to work with in mapreduce, but the results are awesome. Thanks again